# How to Highlight the [Already Colored] selected ListItem in the ListView

Tags: android, listview, selector, highlight, android-selector

I have two `ListFragment` + Single Fragment all in a single `Activity`. The First list show a list of lessons which upon selecting a lesson you are shown second list which contain topics and upon selecting a topic editor opens, Lessons and Topics are colored by users by LongClicking them (Via `ColorChooserDialog`)..

```
package com.fins.newyeartable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LessonListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final int REQUEST_COLOR = 0;
    private static final String DIALOG_COLOR = "color";
    private static final String DIALOG_SETTING = "setting";

    private ArrayList<Lesson> mLessons;
    private Callbacks mCallbacks;

    public interface Callbacks{
        void onLessonSelected(int lessonId);
        void onTableChange();
    }

    @Override 
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mCallbacks = (Callbacks)activity;
    }

    @Override 
    public void onDetach(){
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        mLessons = MyTable.get(getActivity(), AppSetting.getTableType()).getLessons();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lessonlist, parent, false);

        LessonAdapter adapter = new LessonAdapter(mLessons);
        setListAdapter(adapter);


        ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setLongClickable(true);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Lesson lesson = ((LessonAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                ColorChooserDialog dialog = ColorChooserDialog.newInstance(lesson.getId(), -1);
                dialog.setTargetFragment(LessonListFragment.this, REQUEST_COLOR);
                dialog.show(fm, DIALOG_COLOR);
                return true;
            }
        });
        //listView.setSelector(android.R.color.darker_gray);

        return v;
    }

    private class LessonAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Lesson>{

        public LessonAdapter(ArrayList<Lesson> lessons){
            super(getActivity(), 0, lessons);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            if(convertView == null)
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_lesson, null);

            //Link Data to View
            final Lesson lesson = getItem(position);
            TextView titleTextView =  (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_textView);
            titleTextView.setText(lesson.getTitle());

            switch(lesson.getColor()){
            case Lesson.NO_COLOR:
                titleTextView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
                break;
            case Lesson.COLOR_BLUE:
                titleTextView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0099CC);
                break;
            case Lesson.COLOR_GREEN:
                titleTextView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF99CC00);
                break;
            case Lesson.COLOR_YELLOW:
                titleTextView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF44);
                break;
            case Lesson.COLOR_RED:
                titleTextView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF4444);
                break;
            }

            return convertView;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        Lesson lesson = ((LessonAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
        mCallbacks.onLessonSelected(lesson.getId());
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_COLOR){
            ((LessonAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

What I want: to show users selected lesson and topic so they wont get confused while they edit details in editor fragment. I can't use Selectors like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:state_activated="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</selector>
```

Because I already have to color `ListItem` by the color chosen by users the selector color wont appear in the colored list Items, so what selector is usable here? Can I just change the alpha of selected `ListItem`? Or can I add the item color over selector drawable?

Here Picture of app running:
[UI Snapshot](http://uploads.im/TZaO9.png)

Comment: If you're using Material Design, you can set a higher z-axis value to display the item on top. If you're not, I'd go for another shade of the same color palette.

Comment: The position of items are fixed in the list, I just want to change the color sightly to show that the item is selected. But Selectors can't understand the color of items so I am left with a solid single color selector..

Comment: I know they are fixed in the list, by z-index I meant this: [Assign Elevation To Your Views](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html#Elevation)

Comment: sorry, I checked your link, it seems elevation can do the trick. now I just have to use it with selector in order to elevate the Item's View.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Use `View`'s Elevation property to give your items that "selected" look. 
More info in [Assign Elevation To Your Views](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html#Elevation)

Answer (score 0):

It seems by changing Color Value (Alpha value to be precise) from 0xFFXXXXXX to 0xAAXXXXXX or any lower value for alpha the darker_gray color of selector would be visible through TextView background:

```
switch(lesson.getColor()){
        case Lesson.NO_COLOR:
            titleTextView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
            break;
        case Lesson.COLOR_BLUE:
            titleTextView.setBackgroundColor(0xAA0099CC);
            break;
        case Lesson.COLOR_GREEN:
            titleTextView.setBackgroundColor(0xAA99CC00);
            break;
        case Lesson.COLOR_YELLOW:
            titleTextView.setBackgroundColor(0xAAFFFF44);
            break;
        case Lesson.COLOR_RED:
            titleTextView.setBackgroundColor(0xAAFF4444);
            break;
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Right now, colors appear to be drawn on top of ListSelector but It's still ok as it shows what item is selected.. Ofc it's not a good design but still a fast shortcut to do the job.